# Get the seventh digit from an integer

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

I have a integer of 10 digits. I need to get the 7th digit of that integer.

I have found a mathematical solution to get the first digit of an integer.

```cs
var myDigit = 2345346792;

var firstDigit = Math.Abs(myDigit);
while (firstDigit >= 10)
{
     firstDigit /= 10;
}
```

How can I get the seventh digit from myDigit? I am trying to avoid casting to string and doing a substring. I would like to see the mathemathical version of getting the seventh digit.

Anyone?

Comment: Identifiers can't start with digits.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int getSeventhDigit(int number)
{
    while(number >= 10000000)
        number /= 10;

    return number % 10;
}
```

This will take the last digit of numbers with 7 or less digits.

For numbers with 8 or more digits, it will divide by 10 until the number is 7 digits long, then take the last digit.

Comment: Thanks! this works nicely....and I figured the math part out. I forgot that the code reads from right to left so it was actually the 4th digit from right I needed.

Comment: A side question:
How do I retrieve the 5th and 6th number as a pair?

Comment: To get the 5th and 6th digits, change the number in the while loop to `1000000`, and return `number % 100`. That will return a number from 0 to 99.

Answer (score 13):

```
var seventh_digit = ( myDigit/1000000 ) % 10;
```

Comment: A side question: How do I retrieve the 5th and 6th number as a pair?

Comment: `var fifth_and_sixth = ( myDigit/10000 ) % 100;`

Answer (score 6):

Mathematical solution without while loops:

```
int myDigit = 2345346792;

var seventh = (myDigit / 1000000) % 10;

//result should be 5, your seventh digit from the right
```

Comment: A side question: How do I retrieve the 5th and 6th number as a pair?

Comment: @codingjoe (myDigit / 10000) % 100

Answer (score 5):

More generally, you can create a (zero-based) array from the digits:

```
uint myDigit = 2345346792;

int[] digits = new int[10];
for (int i = 9; i >= 0; i--)
{
    digits[i] = (int)(myDigit % 10);
    myDigit /= 10;
}
```

That should be useful for whatever manipulation you wish to do.

Answer (score 5):

```
var nthDigit = (int)((number / Math.Pow(10, nth - 1)) % 10);
```

Where `nth` is n-th digit of the number.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the "zeroth digit" is the least significant digit, this should do you:

```
    public static int nthDigit( int value , int n )
    {
        if ( n < 0 ) throw new ArgumentException();
        if ( value < 0 ) throw new ArgumentException() ;

        while ( n-- > 0 )
        {
            value /= 10 ;
        }

        int digit = value % 10 ;
        return digit ;
    }
```

Comment: nice now just write this as an extension method for int's and it's perfect :-)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (C code, but should be readily portable):

```
if (n < 1000000)
  return 0;        // no 7th digit
while (n > 9999999)
  n /= 10;         // now in the range [1,000,000..9,999,999]
return n % 10;
```

Comment: A side question: How do I retrieve the 5th and 6th number as a pair?

Answer (score 0):

This may seem outdated, but I wanted to get specific digits from a string of numbers and most of these solutions (and others I found) were lacking. So...I decided a workaround and converted the number to a string and then pulled the characters of the string, converting them back to an int. I know this isn't very efficient, but for small projects I don't concern myself with efficiency.

For my task, I was specifically working with phone numbers, so here is my code:

```
long number = 5559876543;
string s = "" + number;

int areaCode = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, 3));
int prefix = int.Parse(s.Substring(3, 3));
int suffix = int.Parse(s.Substring(6, 4));
```

I hope this helps anyone looking for a similar solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetNthDigit(this int value, int digits)
{
    double mult = Math.Pow(10.0, digits);

    if (value >= mult)
    {
        while(value >= mult)
            value /= 10;

        return value % 10;
    }

    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Digits greater than value");
    }
}
```