# Get a pair of integers from an integer

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get the seventh digit from an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752726/get-the-seventh-digit-from-an-integer)

I have an integer and I want a pair number from it.

```
var myDigit = 2345346792;
```

I need the 5th and 6th number out from myDigit namely 34.

What is the mathematical way of getting them without any use of substring?

Additional question from my previous thread:
[Get the seventh digit from an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13752726/get-the-seventh-digit-from-an-integer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat your previous solution, using `100` instead of `10` for the modulus and adjusting the division.